# solr 8.2 search across fields with df

Tags: solr

I have a collection with 5 fields say a,b,c,d,e. currently it works like q=a:value but I want to search across fields (like q=value)

I tried the below in the solrConfig.xml but no luck.Appreciate any pointers

```
<initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text1</str>
    </lst>
<copyField source="a" dest="text1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="b" dest="text1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="c" dest="text1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="d" dest="text1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="f" dest="text1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  </initParams>

<fields>
<copyField source="a" dest="text1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="b" dest="text1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="c" dest="text1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="d" dest="text1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="f" dest="text1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

</fields>
```

Comment: where is the text1 field defined?

Comment: <fields>
    <field name="a" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
 <field name="b" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
 ....
    <field name="text1" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />

</fields>

<copyField source="a" dest="text1"/>
<copyField source="b" dest="text1"/>
.
.
..

Comment: if i mention like above, how to specify the df value?

Comment: i dont see the text1 field, df value is mentioned correctly

Comment: copy fields are defined in schema.xml...you can refer the schema files in solr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `edismax` query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html) and supply the `qf` parameter. It'll also allow you to boost hits in each field differently. `qf=a^5 b` will give hits in the `a` field five times more weight than hits in the `b` field.

Since the field specification is in the `qf` argument now, the `q` parameter can be used as a more simple user typed query instead - `q=foo bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a copy field named "text1", copy all your searchable fields into this field and specify it as default search field.

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="df">text1</str>
```

Add the field in the `schema.xml`

```
<fields> 
   <field name="a" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
   <field name="b" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
   .
   .
  <field name="text1" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" /> 
</fields>
```

You can add fields to be copied to a copy field as follows:

```
<copyField source="a" dest="text1"/>
<copyField source="b" dest="text1"/>
...
<copyField source="e" dest="text1"/>
```

Comment: Where is the schema.xml file located.. I searched insdie solr-8.2.0 but unable to find one.. Does this need to be created?